# PowerBI Rest API loop through different URLs

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to get all the values in Power BI from Rest API but unfortunately result is limited to 10 and I would like to iterate through all until it will not return any data.

So the URL is like "https://web.com/api/v1/devices/?after_device_id=**0**" which will show me 10 first devices so the next iteration would be "https://web.com/api/v1/devices/?after_device_id=**10**" and so on.

> ```
> let
>     apiUrl = "https://web.com/api/v1/devices/",  
>     options = [Headers=[#"APIToken"="XXXX",#"Authorization"="XXXX", #"Accept"="application/json"]],
>
>     result = Json.Document(Web.Contents(apiUrl , options)),
>     devices = result[devices],
>     #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(devices, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error)
> in
>     #"Converted to Table"
> ```

Comment: See https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Power-Query/REST-API-Paging-Power-Query/m-p/1032764#M34979

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if someone would wonder it was made by making function and query.

Function (fDevices):

> ```
> (Page as number)=>
> let
>     apiUrl = "https://web.com/api/v1/devices/"&Number.ToText(Page),  
>     options = [Headers=[#"APIToken"="XXXX",#"Authorization"="XXXX",#"Accept"="application/json"]],
>
>     result = Json.Document(Web.Contents(apiUrl , options)),
>     devices = result[devices],
>     #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(devices, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error)
> in
>     #"Converted to Table"
> ```

Query:

> ```
> List.Generate(()=>
>     [Result= try fDevices(0) otherwise null, Page=0],
>     each [Result] <> null,
>     each [Result = try fDevices([Page]+10) otherwise null, Page=[Page]+10],
>     each [Result])
> ```